# class giving not reading the form input on button click

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, visual-studio

i have a class that takes search input and uses it to query a database table.
however when i press the button and call the class, i see that it shows that there is nothing in the input box ,and just shows me my messageBox message which says invalid search input(catering for nothing entered).

how can i make the class to read whats in the form search text box at the right time so that it can process further information to go on with its fucntion.

here is code for the class:

```
public  static string s;
    public static updateEmployeeForm uF = new updateEmployeeForm();
    public static void selectAndDisplay()
    {

        if ((uF.textID.Text.Length==0))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter valid input to search by");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if (uF.textID.Text.Length > 0)
                {
                    s = "select * FROM mydb.employees WHERE id =" + int.Parse(uF.textID.Text);//declare variable called column that will contain a table column name set to be updated.

                    uF.colName = "id";
                    uF.updatingVar = uF.textID.Text;
                    uF.query4 = "Update mydb.employees SET name ='" + uF.nameTextBoxU.Text + "', surname='" + uF.surnameTextBoxU.Text + "', dept='" + uF.deptTextBoxU.Text + "', cost_center='" + uF.costCeTextBoxU.Text + "' ,address = '" + uF.addressTextBoxU.Text + "', dob= '" + uF.dobTextBoxU.Text + "',  tel1= '" + uF.tel1TextBoxU.Text + "', tel2= '" + uF.tel2TextBoxU.Text + "' ,tel3= '" + uF.tel3TextBoxU.Text + "', email= '" + uF.emailTextBoxU.Text + "', commission= '" + uF.commTextBoxU.Text + "', total_commission= '" + uF.totalCommTextBoxU.Text + "', sick_leave= '" + uF.sickLTextBoxU.Text + "', annual_leave= '" + uF.annualLTextBoxU.Text + "',  family_leave= '" + uF.familyLTextBoxU.Text + "', other_leave= '" + uF.otherLTextBoxU.Text + "',client_care_access='" + uF.clientCareChBox.Checked + "', sale_system_access='" + uF.StaffSystChBox.Checked + "', sale_system_access ='" + uF.SalesSystChBox.Checked + "', uploads_access='" + uF.UploadsChBox.Checked + "' WHERE id= '" + uF.updatingVar + "';";
                }

                else if (uF.idNumSearchTxtBox.Text.Length > 0)
                {
                    s = "select * FROM mydb.employees WHERE id_num ='" + uF.idNumSearchTxtBox.Text + "';";
                    uF.colName = "id_num";
                    uF.updatingVar = uF.idNumSearchTxtBox.Text;
                    uF.query4 = "Update mydb.employees SET name ='" + uF.nameTextBoxU.Text + "', surname='" + uF.surnameTextBoxU.Text + "', dept='" + uF.deptTextBoxU.Text + "', cost_center='" + uF.costCeTextBoxU.Text + "' ,address = '" + uF.addressTextBoxU.Text + "', dob= '" + uF.dobTextBoxU.Text + "',  tel1= '" + uF.tel1TextBoxU.Text + "', tel2= '" + uF.tel2TextBoxU.Text + "' ,tel3= '" + uF.tel3TextBoxU.Text + "', email= '" + uF.emailTextBoxU.Text + "', commission= '" + uF.commTextBoxU.Text + "', total_commission= '" + uF.totalCommTextBoxU.Text + "', sick_leave= '" + uF.sickLTextBoxU.Text + "', annual_leave= '" + uF.annualLTextBoxU.Text + "',  family_leave= '" + uF.familyLTextBoxU.Text + "', other_leave= '" + uF.otherLTextBoxU.Text + "',client_care_access='" + uF.clientCareChBox.Checked + "', sale_system_access='" + uF.StaffSystChBox.Checked + "', sale_system_access ='" + uF.SalesSystChBox.Checked + "', uploads_access='" + uF.UploadsChBox.Checked + "' WHERE id_num= '" + uF.updatingVar + "';";
                }
                else if (uF.nameSearchTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
                {
                    s = "select * FROM mydb.employees WHERE name ='" + uF.nameSearchTextBox.Text + "';";
                    uF.colName = "name";
                    uF.updatingVar = uF.nameSearchTextBox.Text;
                    uF.query4 = "Update mydb.employees SET name ='" + uF.nameTextBoxU.Text + "', surname='" + uF.surnameTextBoxU.Text + "', dept='" + uF.deptTextBoxU.Text + "', cost_center='" + uF.costCeTextBoxU.Text + "' ,address = '" + uF.addressTextBoxU.Text + "', dob= '" + uF.dobTextBoxU.Text + "',  tel1= '" + uF.tel1TextBoxU.Text + "', tel2= '" + uF.tel2TextBoxU.Text + "' ,tel3= '" + uF.tel3TextBoxU.Text + "', email= '" + uF.emailTextBoxU.Text + "', commission= '" + uF.commTextBoxU.Text + "', total_commission= '" + uF.totalCommTextBoxU.Text + "', sick_leave= '" + uF.sickLTextBoxU.Text + "', annual_leave= '" + uF.annualLTextBoxU.Text + "',  family_leave= '" + uF.familyLTextBoxU.Text + "', other_leave= '" + uF.otherLTextBoxU.Text + "',client_care_access='" + uF.clientCareChBox.Checked + "', sale_system_access='" + uF.StaffSystChBox.Checked + "', sale_system_access ='" + uF.SalesSystChBox.Checked + "', uploads_access='" + uF.UploadsChBox.Checked + "' WHERE name= '" + uF.updatingVar + "';";
                }
                else if (uF.surnameSearchTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
                {
                    s = "select * FROM mydb.employees WHERE surname ='" + uF.surnameSearchTextBox.Text + "';";
                    uF.colName = "surname";
                   uF.updatingVar = uF.surnameSearchTextBox.Text;
                    uF.query4 = "Update mydb.employees SET name ='" + uF.nameTextBoxU.Text + "', surname='" + uF.surnameTextBoxU.Text + "', dept='" + uF.deptTextBoxU.Text + "', cost_center='" + uF.costCeTextBoxU.Text + "' ,address = '" + uF.addressTextBoxU.Text + "', dob= '" + uF.dobTextBoxU.Text + "',  tel1= '" + uF.tel1TextBoxU.Text + "', tel2= '" + uF.tel2TextBoxU.Text + "' ,tel3= '" + uF.tel3TextBoxU.Text + "', email= '" + uF.emailTextBoxU.Text + "', commission= '" + uF.commTextBoxU.Text + "', total_commission= '" + uF.totalCommTextBoxU.Text + "', sick_leave= '" + uF.sickLTextBoxU.Text + "', annual_leave= '" + uF.annualLTextBoxU.Text + "',  family_leave= '" + uF.familyLTextBoxU.Text + "', other_leave= '" + uF.otherLTextBoxU.Text + "',client_care_access='" + uF.clientCareChBox.Checked + "', sale_system_access='" + uF.StaffSystChBox.Checked + "', sale_system_access ='" + uF.SalesSystChBox.Checked + "', uploads_access='" + uF.UploadsChBox.Checked + "' WHERE surname= '" + uF.updatingVar + "';";
                }
```

and here code for its call in the form im calling it with:

```
    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updatingDatareadingClass.selectAndDisplay();
    }
```

Comment: dont mind the other queries in else if clauses im just using one for testing curently

Comment: put a break point, and look at the value of your `uF.textId.Text`. that should point you in the right path

Comment: i did put a break point  at `uF.textId.Text` and its always empty " " even after inputing something . which is my biggest question why???

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new instance of the form and not using the original (Where the input value will be stored).

You could use the original textbox value `textID.Text` or ensure that your `uF` form is showing by doing:

```
uf.Show(); // This will then allow you to use `uF.textID.Text` correctly.
```

Also you should read up on SQL Injection as your form is injectable, for instance a user could enter their name as `test or 1 = 1` which would allow then access to your application or even worse, `DROP TABLE mydb.employees;` which would delete your entire employees table.

Comment: where exactly should i put the uF.Show();  for it to be effectual, as in where in the class..beginning or somewhere else @Darren Davies

Comment: @darrenmarela - whenever you need it to be displayed to the user. By default the original Form loads so you could use that and reference `textID.text` directly (Not the `uF` instance).

Comment: when i try to access the Form textBoxes from the class i get the message: the name___ does not exist in the current context thats why i thought of creating an instance of the form to access its objects